# Resolve docker-compose container names from host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What the best way expose docker hostnames outside?

I have zookeeper + kafka cluster running in docker, orchestration by docker-compose. I want have access to kafka and zookeeper by hostnames from my IDE. Is a any native ways to do it? or i should use external dns server?

Just exposing ports will not help, because of kafka design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve thise issue by using:

- In docker-compose: **network_mode: "host"**
- In docker engine: **--net=host**

, which is tells Docker to skip placing the container inside of a separate network stack, [see more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)

I have [demo project](https://github.com/volkodavs/redis-failover), so you can take a look.

Comment: Hi @Serge The first link is broken

Comment: @KingCrunch Docker releases new versions very often and link to their site because unavailable